# why I am not getting precise line/column debug info from LLVM

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++, llvm-ir

I am writing a very simple LLVM pass to simply iterate over all instructions in a function.

```
bool TestInstrument::runOnFunction(Function &F)
{
    for (inst_iterator it = inst_begin(F), E = inst_end(F); it != E; ++it)
    {
        std::string str;
        llvm::raw_string_ostream ss(str);
        ss << *it;
        errs() << ss.str() << "\n";

        const DebugLoc &location = (&(*it))->getDebugLoc();
        if (location)
            std::cout << " see line:  " << location.getLine() << ", col " << location.getCol() << " \n";
        else
            std::cout << "no debugloc information detected\n";
    }
    return true;
}
```

I built my pass using the following command

```
clang -emit-llvm -S -fno-discard-value-names -c hello.c
opt -load ../build/InstrumentPass.so -Instrument -S hello.ll -o hello.instrumented.ll

opt -load ../build/SecondInstrumentPass.so -SecondInstrument -S hello.ll -o hello.second.instrumented.ll
clang -o hello ../lib/util.c hello.second.instrumented.ll
```

When I run the above instrument pass on a very simple hello world c program, I can see print out for each instruction that were iterated. However, none of instruction has debugloc information found. all printout for the location shows "no debugloc information detected\n".

here is the output printed

```
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4
no debug info!
  store i32 0, i32* %retval, align 4
no debug info!
  %call = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([12 x i8], [12 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0))
no debug info!
  ret i32 0
no debug info!
```

Is there any reason why location metadata is not found? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may have compiled without debugging info.

Comment: thanks @arnt, I added the command I use to build my pass. Is there anything wrong in my compilation that excluded debug info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason I didn't get any debugloc info is that in my build command, I used

```
clang -emit-llvm -S -fno-discard-value-names -c hello.c
```

should have used

```
clang -emit-llvm -S -fno-discard-value-names -c hello.c -g
```

the -g option enables debug info.